# When does BufferedWriter create file?

Tags: java, file, bufferedwriter

Using BufferedWriter.write() when is a file created?

I know from the docs that when the buffer is filled it will flush to file, does this mean that:

every-time the buffer is filled an incomplete file will appear on my file system?

or that the file is only created when the BufferedWriter is closed?

My concern is that I am writing files to a directory using a BufferedWriter and another process is polling the directory for new files and reading them. I do not want an incomplete file to be created and be read by the other process.

Answer (score 4):

> Using BufferedWriter.write() when is a file created?

Never. `BufferedWriter` itself *just* writes to another `Writer`. Now if you're using a `FileOutputStream` or a `FileWriter` (where the first would probably be wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter`) the file is created (or opened for write if it already exists) when you construct the object, i.e. before you've actually written any data.

> My concern is that I am writing files to a directory using a BufferedWriter and another process is polling the directory for new files and reading them. I do not want an incomplete file to be created and be read by the other process.

One typical way of handling this is to write to a staging area and then rename the file into the correct place, which is usually an atomic operation. Or even write the file into the correct directory, but with a file extension which the polling process won't spot - and then rename the file to the final filename afterwards.

Comment: I have wrapped a 'FileWriter' in a 'BufferedWriter'. I passed a filename as the 'FileWriter''s constructor, yet no new file was made, and even when the file already existed, it wasn't overwritten. Is 'FileWriter' supposed to create files if they don't already exist?

Comment: @Ungeheuer: Yes, and it does. I'm skeptical of your claims, to be honest. It sounds like maybe you're expecting the file to be created in the wrong place - easy to do if you're using a relative filename and aren't aware of what the current working directory is.

Comment: I checked my code after reading your response and discovered an exception was being thrown by a line before the writing. No stacktrace printed, so I wasn't aware of it. I'll keep your warning in mind.

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedWriter` doesn't create a file as Jon Skeet said. And you cannot guarantee that another process won't read an incomplete file when it is being written to disk. But there are two things you can do:

1. Lock the file so that the other process cannot read it before writing is complete. There are several questions concerning file locking in Java on this site (search for "[java] lock file").
2. Create the file with another filename (ie. use an extension that is not being looked for by the other process) and rename it when writing is finished.